# Send values to fields in a docusign template

Tags: docusignapi

Can I prepopulate the Title or Full Name tag in a template of Docusign?
I'm embedding a enveloped created from a template, but I would like to send those values to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Full Name will grab the "Recipient Name" that is assigned on Sending (or updated by the Signer if that setting is enabled). If you're trying to get another name than the Signer, you will want to use a standard Data Tag (`textTab`).

Title will grab the "Title" that is assigned to that user on their DocuSign Account, it is not able to be over-written as a Sender.